# How to describe when an issue seems very easy

Tags: idiom, idiomaticity

What is the idiomatic expression or phrase for things if it is very easy to overcome or to solve? 
E.g. "It's a piece of cake"that is english version. what i understand from that expression is:it is very easy.In my language we say:it is a game of a child. We could say simply in german "das ist ganz einfach" but that seems to me not idiomatic